# Difference between ViewProviders and Services in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Consider this code:

```
var SearchResultComponent = ng.core.Component({
    selector: "search-result",
    directives: [ng.router.ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, FormComponent],
    viewProviders: [ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS],
    templateUrl: "componentTemplates/SearchResult.html"
}).Class({
    constructor: [ng.http.Http, function( http) {
        this.http = http;
    }],
    ngOnInit: function(){
    }
})
```

Here we provided viewProviders ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS and the service we injected is ng.http.Http. So what's the difference between them. Why do we need ViewProviders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providers are used by Angular's dependency injection (DI) to resolve dependencies.

Providers and services are not "either or", but "as well as"

If your component or service has a dependency (like `ng.http.Http`, in your example), DI looks up the providers tree and returns an instance from the first provider it finds.

If the `providers` or `viewProviders` of your component doesn't have a provider for the requested type or token registered, DI checks the parent components providers up to the providers provided by `bootstrap(...)`.

What instance your component or service gets passed to the constructor depends on where the provider for this dependency is registered.

If component B **and** the parent component A have a provider for a specific service registered, then B gets an instance from B. If C, a sibling component  of B, also has a dependency on this service but doesn't have a provider registered itself, it gets a service instance of A.

This way you can define the scope of service instances.

Comment: how to create a view provider? I mean what's the difference in the interfaces of viewProviders and Services.

Comment: The difference is between `providers` and `viewProviders`. And the difference is the scope. While `providers` are provided to the component and all it's ancestors, providers added to `viewProviders` are only for the component itself. See also http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/08/20/host-and-visibility-in-angular-2-dependency-injection.html

Comment: how do we provide `providers` while creating a service i.e., a service dependent on other services. Can u provide the code snippet in ES5

Comment: Just `providers: [Service1, Servic2]`. If `Service2` depends on `Service1` this is enough (or `viewProviders` instead of `providers` to limit the scope)

Comment: How to use the @Optional decorator in ES5. I mean how to define optional services in ES5.

Comment: This might help http://www.bennadel.com/blog/3015-defining-optional-dependencies-arguments-using-es5-in-angular-2-beta-3.htm